# jQuery .html() does not work with hidden divs?

Tags: jquery

function `.html()` works when the item is displayed. but when I add `style="display:none"`, then html() function returns nothing. Is there workaround of this problem? thanks?

Comment: I think you are wrong.  The `html` function should work regardless of the CSS.

Comment: That isn't your problem. Can you add some context, or the selector you're using?

Comment: I think you need to post the code that gives you the error. I can display: none a div and still get $().html() to return the html contents, no problem.

Comment: How are you adding `style="display:none"`? Are you hard coding it?

Comment: Here's my code: <<?php print $field->element_type; ?>  class="field-content accordionContent" style="display:none"><?php print $field->content; ?></<?php print $field->element_type; ?>>

Comment: After looking through firebug I noticed that .html() function actually grabs all the html including div with all the parameters. it is not like innerHtml, isnt it?

Comment: no, .html() returns same stuff as innerHTML.  Maybe $field->content is malformed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does work, see this demo http://jsfiddle.net/jNLqA/

```
<div style="display: none">
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
<pre></pre>
```

and

```
$('pre').text($('div').html());
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to post here as I have also found that .html will fail to get the value of a hidden element if the element is higher up the page than the jQuery code.

If I make the element visible then the code works as expected or if I move the element to be underneath the jQuery then it also works.

This seems to be the answer, at least for me.

**So the easiest fix is just to move the jQuery code to be above the hidden element then .html seems to work on the hidden element.**

This seems like it could be a bug in jQuery as it is rather odd behaviour.
Also if I use the jQuery .hide method to hide the element on page load and then .show to show it before getting the value it still fails if the element is higher which is stranger still.

Robin

Comment: I believe you're loading something through ajax ... and so the element comes later

Answer (score 1):

this works (display hardcoded):

```
<div id='blah' style="display:none">something</div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($('#blah').html());
});
</script>
```

and so does this (changing it with jquery):

```
<div id='blah'>something</div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#blah').attr('style','display:none');
  alert($('#blah').html());
});
</script>
```

and this works too (changing it w/ jquery another way):

```
<div id='blah'>something</div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#blah').hide();
  alert($('#blah').html());
});
</script>
```

sooo...need more info/context from you

EDIT (UPDATE):

example code based on your comment...again, this works:

```
<?php
class blah {
  var $element_type;
  var $content;
}

$field = new blah();
$field->element_type = 'div';
$field->content = 'something';
?>

<<?php print $field->element_type; ?> class="field-content accordionContent" style="display:none"><?php print $field->content; ?></<?php print $field->element_type; ?>>

<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($('div').html());
});
</script>
```

Maybe there is something in $field->content that's breaking your html? missing closing tag or quote or something? Or maybe your jquery selector isn't shiny? What's your selector look like?

Comment: More info in the comment to my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/wgQpg/

Answer (score 0):

I had problem when using id, changed to class and all worked fine